# How do I change the "Authorising..." message that appears when a Blazor PWA application is being refreshed?

Tags: .net-core, blazor, progressive-web-apps

When an asp net hosted BLAZOR Progressive Web Application is refreshed using browser refresh, PWA application performs an authentication roundtrip.  During this time span, main content div displays the text: "Authorising...".  Where does this message originate from?  My objective is to display a spinner-border along with this message so that the user experience an animation.  Here is what I know:

- Initial "Loading..." message appears from the index page in wwwroot.
- For every AutherizeView, Authorizing section can be used to show custom message.

But I'm unable to locate the source of default "Authorising..." message.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are two places that need your intention.

First is in your `App.razor`. The `AuthorizeRouteView` has a property called `Authorizing`, where you can add any `RenderFragement` you want to display during authorizing. [Here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/6b7b31df8fe633ece7f0498cac1e58ebd3b4d769/src/Components/Authorization/src/AuthorizeRouteView.cs#L25) is the line where the `Authorizing...` is set.

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly" PreferExactMatches="@true">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <Authorizing>
                    <span>Your spinner goes here</span>
                </Authorizing>
                <NotAuthorized>
                    @if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                    {
                        <RedirectToLogin />
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <p>You are not authorized to access this resource.</p>
                    }
                </NotAuthorized>
            </AuthorizeRouteView>
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

If you have created the app using the default template, you should see an `AuthenticationPage`. This page has the route `@page "/authentication/{action}"`.

This page content looks like

```
@page "/authentication/{action}"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication
<RemoteAuthenticatorView Action="@Action" />

@code{
    [Parameter] public string Action { get; set; }
}
```

You can change the entire template by adding the corresponding `RenderFragments` which can be found [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Components/WebAssembly/WebAssembly.Authentication/src/RemoteAuthenticatorViewCore.cs)

Here is an example where every fragment has a non-default value

```
@page "/authentication/{action}"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication
<RemoteAuthenticatorView Action="@Action">
    <LoggingIn>
        <span>LoggingIn</span>
    </LoggingIn>
    <Registering>
        <span>Registering</span>
    </Registering>
    <Registering>
        <span>LoggingIn</span>
    </Registering>
    <UserProfile>
        <span>UserProfile is loaded....</span>
    </UserProfile>
    <CompletingLoggingIn>
        <span>CompletingLoggingIn</span>
    </CompletingLoggingIn>
    <LogInFailed>
        <span>Login failed. Reason: @context</span>
    </LogInFailed>
    <LogOut>
        <span>Logout from the application</span>
    </LogOut>
    <LogOut>
        <span>CompletingLogOut</span>
    </LogOut>
    <LogOutFailed>
        <span>Logout failed. Reason: @context</span>
    </LogOutFailed>
    <LogOut>
        <span>LogOutSucceeded</span>
    </LogOut>
</RemoteAuthenticatorView>

@code{
    [Parameter] public string Action { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `Authorizing` of `AuthorizeRouteView` in `App.razor` worked very well.  Thank you @just-the-benno

Comment: It was my pleasure

Comment: Can I remove the Authorizing page? Because it will splash when I am at Login Page that didn’t need to be Authorized